# Can't Connect to Apache2 Server From External Device (in LAN) Nor From External IP?

Tags: server, apache2, firewall

I forwarded ports 80 and 443 for my apache 2 server.
However, if I: try connecting to the server via external IP or try connecting to the server from a local device via my local ip, I cannot gain access into the server. Could this be a firewall issue? I thought Ubuntu had no port restrictions by default?

Comment: Could you update your question with the error you got, apache configuration file and command executed to forwards ports?